# 98 Toyota Camry: Will night rear light failure trip check engine light?

Tags: toyota, camry, diagnostics

A number of faults can trip the check engine dashboard indicator and must be checked with an ODB meter to decisively identify the fault.

I was just informed that "the car's nighttime rear lights don't work."  Does this failure mode trip the check engine dashboard indicator?

Comment: Not sure on your camry, but some cars will notify you via a diagnostics screen on the dash you have a burnt out bulb or such. Your car being a 98 I would be hard pressed to think it would have this feature. I don't believe it would show up as a CEL or viewable through OBDII connection.

Answer (score 2):

Not the check engine light but on newer cars it may set a code in the Body Control Module, which has to be read with a good quality obd scanner, but there is no light for that since it is non critical and not part of the OBD standard yet.

Comment: How does one know if one has a good quality OBD scanner?  Is there a particular feature or make / model?

Comment: That's a mixed bag on the ones in sold parts stores if they can pull BCM codes, ones used by repair shops can for sure.